# Python gets confused when importing .npy file and thinks a dictionary is an ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have data which was saved to a .npy file by a program not written by me (it's Fermipy, written by NASA so shouldn't be incorrect)

I am trying to read the data contained within said .npy file, but Numpy is getting very confused about what the file contains. Here is what I have done to try and look at the .npy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lc = np.load('MyFile.npy')
>>> print lc
```

This is fine, and the result of the print statement looks like this (there is much more data but here are the first few arrays as an example):

```
{'flux100_ul95': array([  1.31418974e-07,   1.58404373e-07,   2.33785235e-07,
         2.33776637e-07,   2.43218023e-07,   1.96931420e-07,
         1.50871217e-07,   1.65862000e-07,   1.44619768e-07,
         1.69857885e-07,   1.77336145e-07,   9.18976408e-08,
         1.06735191e-07,   1.29923136e-07,   1.35271230e-07,
         1.95270788e-07,   2.11516392e-07,   2.49256943e-07,
         4.07615040e-07,   3.51527018e-07,   2.16950822e-07,
         3.66468699e-07,   3.47797978e-07,   3.16190748e-07,
         2.56618718e-07,   1.59492299e-07,   2.14243133e-07]), 'num_free_params': array([7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
       7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8,
       7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
       7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
       7]),'fit_success_fixed': array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)}
```

What I then tried to do is work out what numpy thinks this is:

```
>>> print lc.shape
()
>>> print type(lc)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

This is what confused me, since it's telling me it's a 0-dimensional numpy array, despite the fact that the curly braces {} clearly tell me it's a dictionary.
I tried to pull the data out using a command I found on stackoverflow:

```
>>> keys, values = lc.keys(), lc.values()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

which clearly didn't work since it thinks it's an array.

So my question is, how do I retrieve my data from this file? I can't slice the array because it has 0 dimensions, and I can't call keys from the dictionary because apparently it's not a dictionary.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `lc[()]` or `lc.item()`

Comment: `numpy.save`, the normal creator of a `npy` file, always saves a numpy array.  So if given something else, like a dictionary, it will wrap it in an array, a 0d object dtype.